# Frequency of qubits in qiskit simulators

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience

I am trying to study the effect of dynamical decoupling sequences (Hahn Echo and CPMG) using qiskit's `qasm_simulator` with an added noise model from `ibm_lagos`. While debugging, I realised that I needed the resonant frequency of the qubit to choose the delay times between the rotation gates. Following instructions from here: https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits_advanced/08_gathering_system_information.html, the resonant frequency is $5.23$ GHz. For sanity check, I ran the following circuit:[image: The delay correcponds to 1/resonant frequency].

The delay corresponds to a time of 1/resonant frequency or a rotation of $\pi$ in the Bloch sphere. I expect to get measure the state $|1\rangle$ with unit probability. Instead, I get the state $|0\rangle$ with unit probability.

Does this implies that the qubit has no resonant frequency owing to the backend being a simulator? If yes, how do I model the system correctly? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The qubit frequency is not encoded into the noise model. You can however attach noise to the delay gate. See [here](https://github.com/Qiskit-Extensions/qiskit-experiments/blob/main/qiskit_experiments/test/t2hahn_backend.py).